# UNIX - command to split the file into multiple files with all the lines for every 3 unique values in a column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Consider the below input file.
Input file:

```
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|0-1-2-3|4
0|2|2|4|0-1-2-3|5
0|1|2|3|1-3-2-4|4
0|1|2|3|1-1-3-4|4
0|1|2|3|1-1-3-4|5
0|1|2|3|4-5-2-6|4
0|1|2|3|4-5-2-6|6
0|4|5|3|7-4-2-4|4
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|4
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|5
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|6
0|1|2|3|7-5-2-6|5
```

Based on field 5, for example  0-1-2-3 in the first record, output split files are expected as below
Split file1:

```
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|0-1-2-3|4
0|2|2|4|0-1-2-3|5
0|1|2|3|1-3-2-4|4
0|1|2|3|1-1-3-4|4
0|1|2|3|1-1-3-4|5
```

Split file 2:

```
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|4-5-2-6|4
0|1|2|3|4-5-2-6|6
0|4|5|3|7-4-2-4|4
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|4
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|5
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|6
```

Split file 3:

```
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|7-5-2-6|5
```

Based on column 5, for every 3 unique values in the column the file should be split and should even have all the lines where the value of column 5 is repeated. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A job for awk. Something like:

```
awk -F'|' -v fileformat="/abc/output/file_%04d.txt" -v max=3 -v field=5 '
  NR == 1 {header = $0; next}
  ! ($field in seen) {
    seen[$field]
    if (++n % max == 1) {
      close(out)
      out = sprintf(fileformat, ++f)
      print header > out
    }
  }
  {print > out}' < /abc/input/a.txt
```

Comment: Hi @StéphaneChazelas.. Thanks for answering. I tried using the logic, i am not able to view the output files. Can you please explain the logic once and also help me with a way to place the split files in a specific path?

Comment: @unixlearner. The output files are `file_<x>.txt`. See `fileformat` (the one you want to change if you want the output in different files). That should be pretty straightforward as long as you know the basics of awk. Explaining would just be paraphrasing the code.

Comment: The script is working fine. But i am not able to find the input files generated from the script. Can you help me with this: If the your file is the path as "/abc/input/a.txt", i want the output split files generated to be placed in "/abc/output" folder.

Comment: @unixlearner see edit

Comment: @EdMorton. Good point about `close()` (though here with that  `fileformat`, there's no chance of the file name to be mistakenly taken as `0`). About `!seen[$field]++`, I'll leave it as it is as it's more legible (IMO) and is generally more efficient and has a smaller memory  footprint with at least gawk.

Comment: This solution can be improved by comparing current `$5` only with the fifth field of the previous line. The array with all previous fifth field values doesn't necessary here. That is, this `! ($field in seen) { seen[$field]`, can be changed to this `field != $5 {field = $5;` and the result will be the same.

Comment: @MiniMax, true. Your solution is better on that front.

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1{ h=$0; f=0; c=1 }NR>1{ 
              a[$5]; if(length(a)>3) { f=0;c++; delete a }; 
              fn="file"c".txt"; if(!f) print h > fn; print > fn; f++ 
           }' file
```

- `h=$0` - *header* line
- `f=0` - flag pointing to the moment of printing header line into the next new file
- `c=1` - filename suffix (incremented for each new file)
- `a[$5]` - indexing array `a` with unique values of the 5th field
- `if(length(a)>3) { f=0;c++; delete a }` - initiating next new filename (`c++`) when succeeding 3 unique values. (`delete a` - delete ll items from array `a`)
- `fn="file"c".txt"` - current filename

---

Viewing results:

```
for f in file[0-9]*.txt; do echo "$f"; cat "$f"; echo; done
```

The output:

```
file1.txt
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|0-1-2-3|4
0|2|2|4|0-1-2-3|5
0|1|2|3|1-3-2-4|4
0|1|2|3|1-1-3-4|4
0|1|2|3|1-1-3-4|5

file2.txt
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|4-5-2-6|4
0|1|2|3|4-5-2-6|6
0|4|5|3|7-4-2-4|4
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|4
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|5
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|6

file3.txt
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|7-5-2-6|5
```

Comment: Note that few implementations of `awk` support `length(array)`. `gawk` and `busybox awk` do. bwk's `awk` does since 2002 (inspired by GNU `awk`), so it should work as well on most BSDs nowadays. It works with the `mawk` maintained by @ThomasDickey, but not the one found on Debian and derivatives. It typically doesn't work on _traditional_ Unices like Solaris. It's not POSIX

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, *but not the one found on Debian and derivatives* -  if Ubuntu is a Debian derivative why it's working on my Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: `mawk 'BEGIN{a[0]=123; print length(a)}'` gives me `mawk: line 1: illegal reference to array a` in Ubuntu 16.04 (_mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan_). Do you get anything different?

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest for answering. I am having the input file in folder path say "/abc/input", but iam not able to view the output files. Can you please help me with that and also with redirecting the split output files to a particular path say "/abc/output"?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, *Do you get anything different? * - of course, I'm calling `awk ...` not `mawk`, works fine

Comment: @unixlearner, sure, change filename pattern to this `fn="/abc/output/file"c".txt";` in my answer. Then, to view results: `for f in /abc/output/file[0-9]*.txt; do echo "$f"; cat "$f"; echo; done`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F '|' '
    function print_to_file(str) {
        print str > "file_"file_num;    
    }
    NR == 1 {header = $0;}
    NR > 1 {
        if(!buf) {
            file_num = 1;
            print_to_file(header);
        }
        if(buf != $5) {
            buf = $5;
            cnt++;
        }
        if(cnt > 3) {
            cnt = 1;
            file_num++;
            print_to_file(header);
        }
        print_to_file($0);
    }
' input.txt
```

**Output:**

```
$ tail -n +1 -- file_* # display content of all files with their filenames

==> file_1 <==
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|0-1-2-3|4
0|2|2|4|0-1-2-3|5
0|1|2|3|1-3-2-4|4
0|1|2|3|1-1-3-4|4
0|1|2|3|1-1-3-4|5

==> file_2 <==
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|4-5-2-6|4
0|1|2|3|4-5-2-6|6
0|4|5|3|7-4-2-4|4
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|4
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|5
0|1|2|3|7-4-2-5|6

==> file_3 <==
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
0|1|2|3|7-5-2-6|5
```

Comment: Note that if you never close the files, you run the risk of running out of file descriptors with some `awk` implementations.